# JavaScript Date setTime one liner

Tags: javascript, date, web, google-visualization

Real simple question! I'm trying to create a google chart using datetime objects, which take the Date() objects in JavaScript. Since I'm looping through a bunch of data (from flask), I'd like to be able to create a new Date() object and would just like to know if I'm setting the date object correctly in one line.

Here's what I'm using at the moment `new Date().setTime(1660549080000.0)` and storing this directly in a google charts column, unfortunately something is not working and I'm wondering if its this!

Edit:
Ended up just making a function for it!

```
function timestampGen(timestamp){
        var datenew = new Date();
        datenew.setTime(timestamp);
        return datenew
    }
timestampGen(time);
```

Comment: Could it be because calling `.setTime` mutates the date object, and returns the equivalent of calling `myDate.getTime()` rather than returning the updated date object? Ultimately it depends on how you're using these objects and you haven't demonstrated that clearly in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing it in one line does not return a date object. The reason is setTime [returns the milliseconds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setTime#return_value).

So the line you are coding is basically returning the number you are setting!

You need to do it in multiple lines.

```js
var myDate = new Date();
myDate.setTime(1660549080000.0);
console.log(myDate);
```

or you can just set the [value of the date constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#value) with the milliseconds to get your single line.

```js
console.log(new Date(1660549080000.0));
```